# setState not working properly with substring function inside

Tags: android, flutter, setstate

I am trying to setState from substring function but the setState is not being called every time here's my code:

```
...
onChanged: (e) {
                print(e);
                setState(() {
                  _code = e.substring(0, 6); // The problem!
                });
                if (e.length >= 6) _focusNode.unfocus();
              },
...
```

Comment: Can you provide more description on your context? What is being changed? Why are you using substring? It's better to understand if you provide more code.

Comment: @billion **onChanged** is TextFormField's method invoked each time the value of the TextFormField has changed so here Whenever my TextFormField value has changed I need to set `_code` to the first 6 digits of the value `e`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear. **What's on 'e'** ??

try:

```
let e = toString(e);
e.substring(0,6);
```

Comment: `e` it's the value of the TextFormField whenever it has changed. I need to set `_code` to the first 6 digits of the value `e`

Comment: can you send me the console of 'e' on change??

Comment: it doesn't console anything the code inside `setState` doesn't get executed entirely.